# Nested data structure where children inherit data from parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I'm trying to create a nested data structure that is many layers deep where every "child" can access data from their parent/grandparent/etc...

for example take these data structures:

```
struct GrandChild {
    int someGrandChildData;
};
struct Child {
    int someChildData;
    std::vector<GrandChild> vgrandChild;
};
struct Parent {
    int someParentData;
    std::vector<Child> vchild;
};
struct GrandParent {
    int someGrandParentData;
    std::vector<Parent> vparent;
};
```

The way I'd like to access the data would be like this:

```
void main()
{
    // create and fill in the data
    GrandParent gp;
    for (int pNum = 0; pNum < 3; pNum++)
    {
        gp.vparent.push_back(Parent());
        for (int cNum = 0; cNum < 3; cNum++)
        {
            gp.vparent[pNum].vchild.push_back(Child());
            for (int gcNum = 0; gcNum < 3; gcNum++)
            {
                gp.vparent[pNum].vchild[cNum].vgrandChild.push_back(GrandChild());

                // call function and ONLY pass a GrandChild
                func(gp.vparent[pNum].vchild[cNum].vgrandChild[gcNum]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void func(GrandChild &gc)
{
    int result = gc.someGrandChildData;

    // no need to pass GrandParent, Parent, or Child because
    // GrandChild can access all of the data from them
    result += gc.someChildData; // <<-- how can I achieve something like this
    result += gc.someParentData; // <<-- how can I achieve something like this
    result += gc.someGrandParentData; // <<-- how can I achieve something like this
}
```

I'm trying to do this because I have structures with many data members at each nesting layer and when I call functions it's extremely annoying to have to pass large numbers of arguments into each function call and becomes a mess to keep organized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you though about using polymorphism and virtual functions?

Comment: I have thought about it, but just don't know how to do it. I've used some polymorphism and virtual functions before, but I'm not very well versed in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by keeping track of the **Parent** of every person(let's call it Node). So, for every Node, create an object of its direct Parent inside of it and do that for every layer (GrandChild, Child, Parent.. etc).

So each `GrandChild` will have a `Child` object, each `Child` will have a `Parent` object and each `Parent` will have a `GrandParent` object.

Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
void func(GrandChild &gc)
{
    int DataFromTheGranChild  = gc.DataFromGrandChild;
    int DataFromTheChild      = gc.Child.DataFromChild;
    int DataFromTheParent     = gc.Child.Parent.DataFromParent;
    int DataFromTheGradParent = gc.Child.Parent.GrandParent.DataFromGrandParent;

    //..
}
```

Comment: Ok, to add a little information: it's possible that the data at the GrandParent and Parent levels could get updated after creation. I'd want the Child and GrandChild to get updated as well when this happens. I expect that I'd have to pass a reference of each direct Parent into each Child. Does this become a problem with using vectors?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could try it first. And it should not be a problem. Whenever a change happens, just iterate the vector the way you do already and submit the changes for each child, grandchild.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to only use one type of struct.

```
struct Entity{
    int Data;
    Entity* Child;
    Entity* Parent;
};
```

Comment: What is the size of your structure ? I meant that you should use some kind of pointer.